# Dynamic created JSON String to send via Ajax

Tags: jquery

I have a form and want to send the data via AJAX in a JSON Format over to my PHP File.
I use jQuery to handle all the events.

I now got stuck and try to find for hours to find a way.

My Data String looks right now like this:

search = {name:$('#name').val(),group:$('#group').val()};

But I have now decided that I only want fields send over, if there is actually a Value set in it. So I created the follwoing part:

```
$('#search_form input[type=text]').each(function(n,element){
  if ($(element).val() != '') 
  {
    search_fields = {test :$('#'+element.id).val()};
  }
});
```

I now want to replace the part where it says test with the input field name and than I would have the value sitting next to it. I hope I explain it right. How would I be able to do this? Because it could be up to 3 Input Fields and I want them to add themself if they have a value or leave them out. Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this question:

[Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/serialize-form-to-json-with-jquery)

I think you'll want to look at using JQuery's .serialize() or .param() to make it simpler to get you form value into JSON

Answer (score 1):

you should use something like

```
var search = [];
$('#search_form input[type=text]').each(function(){
    search.push({name: $(this).attr("name"), value: $(this).val()});
});
```

so use `JSON.stringify()` function to encode it as `JSON` string
If you use this solution, you don't need to use `get_object_vars` on `PHP` side

Comment: This seems to work. Thank you very much for your solution !! I hopefully get this now sorted. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of the [serialize function](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) in jQuery?

```
$("#search_form").serialize();
```

Comment: Yes, but than all form fields get send even with empty values or am I wrong about it?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, you'd have to parse them after posting them :/

Answer (score 0):

A simple example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: http://example.com,
    data: $('form').serialize()
});
```